# When is casting Context to Activity allowed?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-alertdialog, android-context

In a `showAlret(String message, Context ctx)` method of an alert Dialog class, I am trying to get a reference to TextView in the dialog's layout XML:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)((MyActivity)ctx).findViewById(R.id.tv_about);
```

Not before calling inflate() of course:

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
View view = li.inflate(R.layout.aboutdialog, null);
```

The problem is that this call returns `tv` as **null**.

Since the code compiles without any warnings, I am assuming that this is due to "illegal" casting of Context to MyActivity.

I have encountered quite a few cases in which casting Context to Activity is the only thing that really works, so why doesn't this work in this case?

When does casting Context to Activity make sense?

What are the "unspoken rules" in this regard?

Comment: You'll have to use tv = showAlret.findViewById() method

Comment: @Jaydeep Khamar What do you mean by this? `showAlret()` is the name of a method in my class, not a name of a class.

Comment: Oh!! I thought that it was the name of AlertDialog..sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
View view = li.inflate(R.layout.aboutdialog, null);
TextView tv = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_about);
```

I understand that your textview is a part of the dialog xml so, you need to findViewById() on the dialogs view instead of the activity.

Comment: you posted the solution 36 seconds before I did... :) Accepted + 1.

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't otherwise you would have exception.
Are you sure that your Activity hs loaded the TextView from xml at the moment you try to get it?

Comment: Indeed, I am having an exception (that's how I came across this). Before I make the call described in the post, I do `callLayoutInflater.inflate()` (see above edit). Isn't this enough? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. My mistake was that I was doing:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)((MyActivity)ctx).findViewById(R.id.tv_about);
```

Instead of:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_about);
```

Answer (score 0):

On a side not, you can cast the context to an Activity when it is an Activity. Context is a base class for Activity.

You should only have to cast to an Activity when your method is not available on the Context object. Casting is just a way to tell the compiler that you are sure that it is an Activity therfore the compiler will asume you know what you are doing.